# Fastest way to append to an existing excel file through visual studio

Tags: excel, visual-studio

I am very new to visual studio (currently using Visual Studio 2013)
and I am trying to append strings from my list to an existing excel file.
Example item in list = "item1,item2,item3,item4"
I am trying to append each item to each cell starting from the last row of the excel file.
The below code works but it is taking too much time on a lower spec pc,
Any idea on how to make it faster?
Or are there any better way to append from my list?
I am not familiar at all dealing with excel.application object

Here are my codes:

```
                Dim excelApp As New Excel.Application
                Dim excelWB As Excel.Workbook
                Dim excelWS As Excel.Worksheet
                excelWB = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filename)
                excelWS = excelWB.Worksheets("Data")
                Dim lastrow = excelWS.Range("A1").SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

                'adding data from list2 to excel file
                For l_index As Integer = 0 To Global_Variable.list2.Count - 1
                    lastrow += 1
                    Dim splitter = Global_Variable.list2.Item(l_index).Split(",")
                    excelWS.Cells((lastrow), (1)).Value = splitter(0) 
                    excelWS.Cells((lastrow), (2)).Value = splitter(1) 
                    excelWS.Cells((lastrow), (3)).Value = splitter(2) 
                    excelWS.Cells((lastrow), (4)).Value = splitter(3) 
                    excelWS.Cells((lastrow), (5)).Value = splitter(4) 
                    excelWS.Cells((lastrow), (6)).Value = splitter(5) 
                    excelWS.Cells((lastrow), (7)).Value = splitter(6) 
                    excelWS.Cells((lastrow), (8)).Value = splitter(7) 
                    excelWS.Cells((lastrow), (9)).Value = splitter(8) 
                    excelWS.Cells((lastrow), (10)).Value = splitter(9) 
                    excelWS.Cells((lastrow), (11)).Value = splitter(10) 
                Next
                Dim Outputname = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filename) + "\RESULT_" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename)
                System.IO.File.Delete(Outputname)
                excelWB.SaveAs(Outputname)
                excelWB.Close(, Outputname)
                excelApp.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you convert list2 to a 2 dimensional array before opening Excel (or better yet just create it that way in the first place), you can simply define a `Range` variable that has the same dimensions & the correct location (`"A" & lastrow') and then set the range's value to the arr.

Ex. With list2 as an array variable that contains 100 items with your 11 attributes (BTW you say VS2013, but you don't say if you're using C#/VB/etc. Based on the use of `DIM` I assumed VB)

```
Dim rng as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range = Nothing

'Set the range
rng = excelWS.Range("A" & lastrow & ":K" & lastrow + list2.GetLength(0))

'Fill the range with the array
rng.Value = list2
```

Short, sweet and generally runs fairly quick

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for this. It helped me and now I understand a lot more how Microsoft.Office.Interop works.